# How to get the index of data in Cesium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I have successfully implemented the tutorial on how to build a flight tracker. I would like to be able to access the index of my data at a current time in my app. In other words, when cesium is showing the animation of the airplane following the flight path, how can I get the current index that the airplane is at? (the index of my data).

I have two entities, one under a loop to generate all the points of the path and another where I load an airplane model. I need to sync other parts of my app with the current state of Cesium. (If I pause Cesium, I need to pause other things, etc.)

Im using Resium. btw. This is my airplane model. It animates according to the position property which is derived from  `const positionProperty = new SampledPositionProperty();`

```
 // this is the loop that draws the path with points
 {flightData.map((data, i) => {
    const time = JulianDate.fromIso8601(data.timestamp);
    const position = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
      data.longitude,
      data.latitude,
      data.height + 5.0
    );
    // here we add a sample, per object in the array 
    positionProperty.addSample(time, position);

    return (
      <Entity
        key={`${i}${position}`}
        position={position}
        point={{ pixelSize: 5, color: PhaseColors[data.phase] }}
      />
    );
  })}

// this is the airplane model that follows the path above
<Entity
style={{ border: "10px solid green" }}
// Here is where we pass the positionProperty sample. How can I get the current index out of this? 
position={positionProperty} 
// Automatically compute the orientation from the position.
orientation={new VelocityOrientationProperty(positionProperty)}
tracked
selected
model={{ uri: model, minimumPixelSize: 100, maximumScale: 100.0 }}
path={
  new PathGraphics({
    width: 3,
    material: Color.fromCssColorString("#202025"),
  })
}
availability={
  new TimeIntervalCollection([
    new TimeInterval({ start: start, stop: stop }),
  ])
}
```

One way I thought was to use the clock and get a timestamp. Using the timestamp I can do a look-up on my own data. But Id like to avoid this, it's pretty costly.

Any Cesium gurus out there? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [`SampledPositionProperty.getValue(...)`](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/SampledPositionProperty.html#getValue).

You have a variable `positionProperty` that is of type `SampledPositionProperty`.  It's marked `const`, but I believe this is incorrect, because you're adding samples to it after construction.

In any case, to get data out of there, you want to call something like this:

```
var currentPos = positionProperty.getValue(clock.currentTime);
```

Note that this returns a full `Cartesian3` position, not an index.  This is because `clock.currentTime` may fall in between indices, and the `positionProperty` will smoothly interpolate in the intermediate times.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. In this case, I would still have to then use that Cartesian3 position to do a look-up on my data.. right?

Comment: It depends. Are you trying to get back the lat/lon/height, at some particular sample time that might be between points?  Or do you really need to index into the original data, to look up some extra information that's not the position?  And if the latter, does that info vary with time, and need interpolation between points?

Comment: The latter for sure. We really need to index the original data. The extra information we need is in order to display text fields (like notifications) along with the data that changes over time. We don't really need interpolation between points, because we can just pick the nearest value.

Comment: Ok. I don't think the Cesium API directly exposes a "get index" helper, but you can check the source for [how Cesium gets the index internally](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/blob/6d94a1e8221bab260cbefb7487a28b4a73281081/Source/DataSources/SampledProperty.js#L369-L383) and do something similar.  Another option would be to initialize a TimeIntervalCollection with the data you need, such as a string that changes its contents with time intervals.  The latter is more "Cesium-like" than searching for raw indices.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected.  If you create a `Cesium.TimeIntervalCollection` with a date range for each of your points, there is a [TimeIntervalCollection.indexOf](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/TimeIntervalCollection.html#indexOf) function that will return the index itself.  This isn't available on a sampled property though, because of the interpolation.

Comment: I have set the availability property of the airplane model to be 
`availability={
          new TimeIntervalCollection([
            new TimeInterval({ start: start, stop: stop }),
          ])
        }
`

Comment: Sure, but availability needs to cover the aircraft's entire flight with a single interval.  I'm suggesting a separate property, maybe "description" or it may just be a custom property in your own code separate from the entity, where you could load all of the smaller intervals into the list (perhaps along with a string description at each interval).  Then you could get the value or get the index at any time.

Comment: Let me try that ! Thank you again for your support <3 What event would recommend me using the `TimeIntervalCollection.indexOf ` in order to get the current Index that my airplane model is at?

Comment: Im currently doing it in the onTick event which does what I need. I just need to throttle because the ticks are too fast.